# TCP receive issue

Tags: c, input, tcp

I am sending some data to a "server" from a client. This is just a tcp connection so once they are connected the stream is open until i close it. Anyways, I send a username to the server. The server tests if this is a valid username and then sends back a message success or fail. If it isn't a valid username the server relistens and the client re asks for a username to test again until you successfully login. The problem I am having is if I enter a wrong username, it send back the response correctly and asks me to resend a new one. However when I enter the right username now, it fails. and then no matter what it sends next time, it succeeds because i had sent it previously but its like its waiting until i enter again. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I am very new to C.I tried resetting all of the variables after each loop but it still isn't working. (YES i know UDP is a way better option for this task..........its part of the spec) here is the server loop

```
int loggedIn = 0;
    char username[MAX];
    char status[10];
    int statusLen=0;
    int counter = 1;
    while(!loggedIn){
        // receive username
        counter = recv(clientSock, username, MAX - 1, 0);
        username[counter] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", username);

        // check if username is in list
        //if in the list, send success
        if(strcmp(username,"test1234") == 0){
            strcpy(status,"success");
            statusLen = sizeof(status);
            send(clientSock, status, statusLen,0);
            loggedIn = 1;
        }else { //if not in the list, send error and recv again
            strcpy(status,"fail");
            statusLen = sizeof(status);
            send(clientSock, status, statusLen,0);
            memset(status,0,statusLen);
        }
    }
    printf("YOU MADE IT FINALLY BUDDY\n");
    //send accounts
```

here is the client loop

```
char username[20];
        //verify login
        int loggedIn = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        char status[10];
        while(!loggedIn){
            printf("Please login with your username: \n");
             scanf(" %s",username);
            //send username to the server
            int usernameLen = strlen(username);
            send(serverSock, username, usernameLen,0);
            //recieve from the server
            counter = recv(serverSock, status, 9, 0);
            status[counter] = '\0';
            //if success
            if(strcmp(status, "success") ==0){
                loggedIn = 1;
            } else {//else reenter the username
                printf("Error: Invalid Username!\n");
                memset(username,0,sizeof(username));
                memset(status,0,sizeof(status));
                counter = 0;
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sent string size can be the the count of characters, not the string size.
In the code:

```
statusLen = sizeof(status);
```

you may do

```
statusLen = strlen(status);
```

as `strlen` counts the characters , not the size of the string. String memory size and characters count aren't necessarily the same in C.
You may read strings with `gets` instead of `scanf`.
`scanf` breaks strings each time it finds a blank space.
And how much is MAX? See if the buffer is enough to fit the recieved data.
Also see if you are recieving the right data, by using a printf. I'm unsure, but looks like you are developing the server too.
Hope this helps. I can't find anything else wrong in your code.

Comment: thank you for the input! i will give these a try and let you know

Comment: you were right! thank you so much. the strlen was the issue. I was also looking into the stdin because of the scanf, but this worked perfectly.. thank you again

Comment: you are welcome. i'm glad it works! and thanks for text formatting. i'm new to stackoverflow and got confused with text formatting here.